# How reuse a instance of a object for all functions requests?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, devops

I am working on a azure function that makes dependency injection of a object, and I would like to know what I can do to it's create the instance just once in the constructor (when I deploy the function to production) and at the others requests to the functions reuse the first instance created.

I made a injection dependency of the object that I want to reuse but it don't worked.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is not working? If you have code that doesn't work but fail to show us that code, it is practically impossible to give you an answer. It is a common reason to close questions here

Comment: It's usually an antipattern to use dependency injection in functions. Just because it gives you the ability to do it doesn't mean you should just lift and shift your web app and turn it into a function. What is the purpose for injecting your dependency?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the use of Startup class for DI in functions? See official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to reuse a resource among multiple instances of the function is to declare it as `static`. For example, let's say I want to reuse an `HttpClient`:

```
public static class PeriodicHealthCheckFunction
{
    private static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    [FunctionName("PeriodicHealthCheckFunction")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo healthCheckTimer,
        ILogger log)
    {
        string status = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:5001/healthcheck");

        log.LogInformation($"Health check performed at: {DateTime.UtcNow} | Status: {status}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "function scope" variable in C# like there is in Native C++. But there is a bunch of similar constructs you can use:

Make a property with Public get but private Set. That way only class code (like the constructor) can set values. You see this pattern used abundantly all over the .NET Framework. However it does not really avoid setting the value in class code by accident. It works best if you never use this value anywhere else in classcode.

Another option is the "readonly" variable attribute. It enforces that the value must be set once (in the Constructor), but can also only be set once. You would still have to hand in the instance to the constructor or use static.

Another option is to add a static variable to store the data. But that is a pattern that is **absolutely not adviseable**. If you never need a second set of these instances with a different shared value, you have lost. And this will happen, as sure as the Garbage Collection. We got literal decades worth of experience of static values backfiring. So you really should stay with instance variables.

Another way is to add a Factory method. Often they are used if the instances need setup you can not leave to the average programmer using your code. You could even slightly breakt the pattern by having both a public constructor and a instance Factory Method. If you use the factory method, the shared thing is copied over from them Instance it is called on. If you use the Public constructor, a new shared thing is created.